# Converting byte[] property to Bitmap in android using ksoap2

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I have this code to get an array of byte. The client is built in ksoap2.

All properties I am getting fine but when I try to get the property which has an image it returns `null` when `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` is executed. And really I get information when I am debugging.

The code I am using is:

```
String result = ((SoapObject)poSoap).getProperty("MyImage").toString();
byte[] bytes = result.getBytes();
Bitmap png = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, <<<png file size>>>);
```

MyImage property is a png file.

As server I am using WCF in C# and i get the file using:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@file);
```

@file is the path to the file, it is working fine.

I think problem is not in server side it is in client side.

Do I have another way to get that property (type byte[]) and convert it to Bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, as I said it was client side, only I needed to decode in base64, my new code is:

```
String result = ((SoapObject)poSoap).getProperty("MyImage").toString();             
byte[] bloc = Base64.decode(result, Base64.DEFAULT);         
Bitmap png = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bloc,0,bloc.length);
```